# Selecting single cell data from selected row - DataGridView

Tags: vb.net

I have a datagridview with data in it, I have set it so you can only select the row and one at a time.

However, I need to get the data from one of the cells in the selected row, I have tried this;

```
Dim data As String = DataGridView1.SelectedRows.Cells(5).toString
```

Something like that, but I can't get the value of it, does anyone know the way to do it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Perhaps the right syntax is:

```
Dim data As String = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(5).Value.ToString
```

See [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.value)

Comment: Not sure where this comes from but in 2019 I am using VS 2013 , and it only works with this code > Dim description As String = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(2).Value.ToString() Selectedrow() throws an error. So I stumbled on e.RowIndex. Now this might be because I was using a Button in the grid and pressing it.

Comment: What is the error thrown? SelectedRows exists still in 2019. Perhaps is something connected to the Remarks section of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectedrows?view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 6):

```
Dim data As String = YourDataGrid.Item("YourColumnHere", YourDataGrid.CurrentRow.Index).Value
```

hope this help!

Answer (score 2):

SelectedRows requires an index parameter. If you've set it to only select one row, then it will always be 0.  Try changing that line to:

```
Dim data As String = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(5).Value.toString()
```

Comment: its odd, it gives me the data as the string "DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(5).toString" as the data. also, when i select higher than cell 5 i get the error that the argument was out of range

Comment: The 5 relates to the amount of columns.  If you get an argument out of range exception for that it means you are trying to access a column that doesn't exist.  Bear in mind for that that indexes start at 0, so the fifth column will have an index of 4.

Comment: Hmm very odd, i select row 4, which is downloads and the string comes out as: DataGridViewTextBoxCell7BColumnIndex=4,RowIndex=7D

Answer (score 0):

'hope this code is also another way............
DataGridView1.SelectedRows(DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index).Cells(5).Value.ToString()

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use ordinal numbers to identify which row you have selected, if this call is being used inside an event that is related to the datagridview, there should be a value passed to the event called "e" which is a structure of event arguments.
if e.RowIndex is valid for that eventarg structure, you can use it as the value of the row selected:

> Dim strCellValue as string = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(6).Value

You can also get e.ColumnIndex from that argument.